# Distance lines are not showing in interface editor

Tags: xcode, xcode6

after installing latest Mac OS X (El Capitan) I found that distance lines inside Xcode interface editor does not appear anymore after pressing alt key. I do not know if system update has something to do with it ... maybe I just pressed some kind of key configuration which disabled distance guides. Did someone ever had similar situation? Below I attached link to image which exactly shows lines I am talking about.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qoy8wvvddxxaupy/2015-10-06_1341.png?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so It turned out that the problem was in having two Xcode versions installed on one machine. I mean that currently I have Xcode 6.4 and 7.1 on my mac and version 6.4 behaves sometimes quite strange (for example I am not able to add new source file directly to project because I am not able to choose any group option). 7.1 is ok. So if you have some problems in similar configuration then get rid of Xcode 6.